# Y-Axis and Data labels do hot have precision and show the same number

Tags: wpf, scichart

We are using SciChart v6.3.013476 for WPF. We noticed the when Y-data has low variance with respect to the data values, the Y-Axis and the data labels just show the same number.

> (e.g. y-value range 0.10000758**25** - 0.10000758**58**). All Y-Axis labels will be 0.1

There is no precision and the plot looks meaningless.

[Our Problem with scichart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4civ.png)

[A reference image with a similar data-set shows our expectation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sSxD.png)

A good plotting library should be able to visualize any data in a meaningful way. We are aware of the Scale and Offset APIs, but such a requirement should be a part of the plotting library itself. Especially with real-time data.

Are we missing something obvious?

Comment: Are you binding to an axis in your XAML?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple problem to solve. You need to adjust the [TextFormatting](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Labels%20-%20TextFormatting%20and%20CursorTextFormatting.html) property of SciChart or use the [LabelProvider](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Labels%20-%20LabelProvider%20API.html) feature to format labels

By default:

- SciChart uses a .NET Formatting string on [Axis.TextFormatting](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Labels%20-%20TextFormatting%20and%20CursorTextFormatting.html) property
- This is set by default to "0.00" so if your y-values are 0.011, 0.012 they will all round to 0.01
- You can adjust [TextFormatting](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Labels%20-%20TextFormatting%20and%20CursorTextFormatting.html) to display more decimal places. Try "0.0#####" for example
- You can set values in engineering format if you use TextFormatting equal to "#.#E+0"
- If you want fine grained control and dynamic label formatting, use the [LabelProvider API](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Labels%20-%20LabelProvider%20API.html)